# I have 200 errors in Xcode project made in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

everything was working fine and I tested the game on my iPhone, but there was no simulators, so I changed the supported platform in the build settings to "IOS"
and suddenly 200 errors as in the picture.

[image]

Comment: I'd start by Googling the error message(s). If it's an issue introduced by some software update, you're not the only one who has it.

Comment: are you sure you chose "Run in Xcode" as **release**?  (not "debug").  Also, it does look like you simply have to update Xcode.

Comment: Did you see *... was built for newer iOS version (9.0) than being linked (6.0)* ?

Comment: Actually, the fact that anyone has downvoted this question is quite wrong. It's completely common in using Unity that some specific mistake (perhaps a setting or plugin issue) can result in builds collapsing in the later pipeline (Android, iOS or otherwise).  It's a totally "normal" problem in Unity and can be hard to figure out.  I can't quite figure out what this one would bel it's possibly my suggestion above.

Comment: Look at BuildSettings panel, "Run in Xcode".
Are you sure you chose Release? (never "Debug").

Comment: Downvoting this question is unnecessary. This kind of problem is a common and not always straightforward issue when building with unity. JaafarBk (OP) did not create the project that breaks, it's autogenerated by Unity. Also, I'm not sure if updating XCode is the right way here, these window decorations look like Yosemite or El Captain - and I'm pretty sure on these he would have a newer iOS SDK then just 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get rid of most XCode errors during build is to just remove that XCode project and create a new one. Unity rebuilds it every time you build, but sometimes somethings get "stuck".

Also, please post your project's Unity build properties. Perhaps you have build for debug? Which iOS version are you building for? The lowest one available in the dropdown is usually the best choice.

Do you have any native plugins? Try to remove them one by one and rebuild each time - it's quite possible that one of them breaks your build.

**EDIT:**
It looks like you do have a problematic plugin - are these files at the top of the log (`NICellFactory.o`, `NiTableViewModel.o`) parts of the Nimbus Kit? Do they even have a Unity plugin?